# Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender not rolling files

Tags: java, log4j

I have a log4j configuration that's intended to roll files when the  my application runs once daily:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, filer

log4j.appender.filer=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.filer.File=./logs/daily/daily.log
log4j.appender.filer.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.filer.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.filer.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.filer.append=true
```

...but everytime the application runs, the file `daily.log` gets truncated and overwritten. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try this `log4j.appender.filer.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration should be alright I suspect the following line is causing you problems.

```
log4j.appender.filer.append=true
```

Comment: I added that because if the application ran more than once on the same day (unlikely but not impossible) then I thought that it would append the new data instead of creating a separate file or truncating the existing file, which is what I would want (although maybe DailyRollingFileAppender takes care of that automatically ?)

Comment: @RTF yes it shouldnt created another filed or truncating the data

Comment: how is this the answer?  Someone please explain.